# objective-c how to encode NSArray with UTF8?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have scandinavian alphabets in my array like æ, ø, å. With NSLog the output showed these alphabets as scrambled codes. How to encode NSArray with UTF8? Any help is appreciated.

I tried only:

```
NSArray *nnoWords = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:newNoWords] retain];
NSLog (@"nnoWords: %@ ", nnoWords);
```

newNoWords is a NSMutableArray. nnoWords containt normal objects like NSString hello, pear, apple, etc. taken from a txt file.

---

EDIT 29 august 2011:

nnoWords comes from this, converted to NSMutable and then back to NSArray, thus called nnoWords. And words.txt is encoded in UTF8.

```
     NSArray *noWords = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
        [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"txt"]                                         
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
```

I have also tried:

```
NSString *norsk = @"æ ø å";
    NSLog (@"%@", norsk);
```

And the output is correct:

```
2011-08-29 13:15:23.302 scanner2[29776:207] æ ø å
```

Comment: What's the type of the objects in the array?

Comment: @vikingosegundo more info added.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line with the NSLog and inspect nnoWords. What do the strings in the array look like? Has the textfile utf-8 encoding?

Comment: @ott I know breakpoint, but I dont know how to inspect a nsarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Xcode console. If you view the output from Terminal.app, you will see it is as expected.

Test case:

```
//clang -framework Foundation -o log_utf8 log_utf8.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int
main(void)
{
  NSString *word = @"en ord på Svenska";
  NSLog(@"%@", word);
}
```

Sample output:

```
StackOverflow$ clang -framework Foundation log_utf8.m -o log_utf8
StackOverflow$ ./log_utf8 
2011-08-28 20:10:09.268 log_utf8[65105:707] en ord på Svenska
```

If you are still seeing gibberish when you view the output from something other than Xcode's questionable built-in console, then you need to examine how you're getting your string data:

- How does the text with non-ASCII characters enter your application?
- What encoding does NSString think that text is in?
- What encoding is it actually in? If the text comes from a file, then the `file` command might be able to answer this for you.

Comment: You are right. When I wrote the nsarray noWords to a txtfile, there is no gibberish, so the issue lies in Xcode's built-in console. But how do I solve this?

Comment: You don't; Apple does. File a radar. Since this doesn't actually affect any text displayed in a text label or field or written to a file, it's simply a development inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%S", [[theArray description] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding]);
```

from this question: [NSLog incorrect encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720052/nslog-problem)

Comment: It still doesnt help. The output is like before: It should be "på, etc.", but it shows ""p\U00e5"".