# Can't decode UTF8 characters from NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I use an XML parser to retrieve an xml from server.

And I have the following two things:

```
NSMutableArray *catalogueList;
Catalogue *currentCatalogue;
```

Catalogue looks like this:

```
#import "Catalogue.h"

@implementation Catalogue

@synthesize id_model;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize url;

@end
```

And this piece of code also:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{    
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"catalogue"]) 
{       
    // Add currentCatalogue to array
    [catalogueList addObject: currentCatalogue.url];
}
```

This works great, but there is a little problem. When I do this:

```
 NSLog(@"Valoare url %@", currentCatalogue.url);
```

it displays the correct URL.

But when I do this:

```
 NSLog(@"Valoare url %@", catalogueList);
```

the output is "link".

which is not correct at all: instead of `Coupé` I get `Coup\U00e9`. Please tell me how to obtain in `catalogueList` the correct link with the `é` character.

Comment: This looks more like iOS than Android :)

Comment: This is iphone.See the tags.I corrected the title.Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing an array instead of the object. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"catalogueList url %@", [catalogueList objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Check out this SOF question [NSLog incorrect encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720052/nslog-problem) .
Similar problems with UTF8 characters

Comment: And it displays this <Catalogue: 0x6d3b3c0>

Comment: your `url` variable is a string, right? it's working perfectly at my end

Comment: Write my code instead of `NSLog(@"Valoare url %@", catalogueList);`

Comment: Dude, instead of printing `catalogueList` in `NSLog`, print `[catalogueList objectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3515/discussion-between-george-and-tipycalflow)

Comment: Dude,  i told you that I tried and I got this: <Catalogue: 0x6d973c0>

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your *url* property is a string in the array.

```
@interface Catalogue : NSObject{

NSString *myURL;

}
```

NSString doesn't alter special characters, and should output the exact same thing that went in. The following Assumes you already added the string to the array.

```
NSLog(@"My URL: %@", [currentCatalogue objectAtIndex:0]);

Ouput: My URL: http://host_server/uploads/modeles_pdf/41_TTRS_Coupé_TTRS_Roadster_Tarifs_20110428.pdf
```

Also, Try doing this to see if you get the same error...

```
NSString *temp = currentCatalogue.url;
//Check the string
NSLog(@"NSString temp: %@", temp);

//Add it to the array
[catalogueList addObject:temp];

//Assuming object is at index 0, check the object in the array
NSLog(@"My URL: %@", [catalogueList objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the UTF8 string value and use it

```
[currentCatalogue.url UTF8String];
```

Comment: I tried and got this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a39d My app crashed at that line!

Comment: Sorry my bad - mistyped the variable name. The idea is to get the UTF8String from the string that you are getting from the server. Edited my answer...