# convert NSString to const char *

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to convert the nsstring value into const char *.

```
NSString *s = @"יככעימבבגיננימ"; //Hebrew characters
const char *t = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"\n str = %s",t);
```

The console showed like this "◊ô◊õ◊õ◊¢◊ô◊û◊ë◊ë◊í◊ô◊†◊†◊ô◊û".

How to get the actual NSString value into const char*?

Thanks,
loganathan

Comment: You already have actual NSString value as utf-8 char array and problem related to NSLog output, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/722984/1101537

Answer (score 6):

It's just because `%s` in `NSLog` denotes ASCII string (plain-C 8 bit strings, to be precise), not UTF8.

What about trying the following?:

```
NSString *s = @"יככעימבבגיננימ"; //Hebrew characters
NSLog(@"\n str = %@",s);
```

You can log out UTF16 array, also:

```
const wchar_t *t = (const wchar_t*)[s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"\n str2 = %S",t);
```