# Convert NSString with umlauts to const char *

Tags: encoding, nsstring, char, diacritics

I looked hours to solve this issue, and found nothing. Sorry if answer is somewhere on Internet, I really couldn't find it.

I have a `NSString *header = @"ästrç";` or with any other umlauts from German, Swedish, etc languages.

I need this `NSString` converted to:

```
const char* cString = [header cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Note: `NSASCIIStringEncoding`, `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` not working.

I also tried this:

```
const char *cString = [header UTF8String];
```

Not working.

Can someone help me please? This is very strange.

EDIT:

By "not working" I mean that if I have these chars:
[image: Input]

It will output this:
[image: Output]

I don't care of NSLog. I need that **const char *** for a method to write in PDF:

```
HPDF_Page_TextOut  (HPDF_Page    page, HPDF_REAL    xpos, HPDF_REAL    ypos, const char  *text)
```

Comment: The last one (`-[NSString UTF8String]`) should work. Define "not working".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const char *cString = [header UTF8String]` will work, but you are probably testing it with
`NSLog("%s, cString);`.

NSLog will not work, because `%s` is expecting *ASCII* string not *UTF-8*.

Details: [convert NSString to const char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710248).

Comment: I've already saw that, and many other posts. Just that it doesn't work for what I need. Se my edit above.

Comment: @benyboariu you will have to learn what encoding your `HPDF_Page_TextOut` function accepts.

Comment: I don't know where my mind was. Of course I had to look what encoding that method accepts. Working now. Thank you very much.