# NSLog hebrew characters from csv file in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, csv

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hebrewLesson1and2" ofType:@"csv"]; 
    NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@", rows);
```

My CSV file contains hebrew characters, which I would like to see print out to the console.  Currently they get printed out like "\U05d6\U05b8\U05e7\U05b5\U05df" instead of something like "זָקֵן".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How is `+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile]` implemented?  That's not a standard `NSArray` function.  Your strings might be being unescaped as they're read in.

Comment: may be useful in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710248/convert-nsstring-to-const-char