# Objective - C, NSDictionary encoding in utf-8

Tags: objective-c, encoding, utf-8, nsdictionary, special-characters

I have NSDictionary whom contents I read from a .plist which is encoded in utf-8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ABACİ</key>
    <array>
        <string>ABALİ</string>
        <string>APACİ</string>
        <string>ARAÇİ</string>
    </array>
```

and so on

Anyway, the problem is when I NSLog the contents on this dictionary to the console, I get results like

```
"K\U00d6PEK"
```

this is logged version of another entry which doesn't contain regular latin english characters. The characters I try to use are in UTF-8 encoding.

However, when I read the contents of an array from a text file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words_tr" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *contentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        _wordStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[contentString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```

this works perfectly. I want to do the same for reading from the property list as well. How can I get results encoded in UTF-8 for the NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to NSLog by this?

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:contentString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: That is not what I want. I want to access the NSDictionary with proper encoding and compare the keys with user inputs. That NSString was just an example.

Comment: well, my guess to your question is that NSLog normally not support UTF8 string. so it display incorrect, however your string is correct. easier to test by assign your string to UILabel.

Comment: That is indeed correct. I didn't know NSLog didn't support UTF8. Thanks! Do you know if there is anyway to make it support? I looked through the preferences but I had no luck.

Comment: There is good answers here how to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720052/nslog-problem

Answer (score 1):

```
+(NSString*)utf8toNString:(NSString*)str{
    NSString* strT= [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U" withString:@"\\u"];
    //NSString *strT = [strTemp mutableCopy];
    CFStringRef transform = CFSTR("Any-Hex/Java");
    CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)strT, NULL, transform, YES);

    return strT;
}
```