# How to save greek characters to sqlite in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, special-characters

I've search everywhere on Internet but i didn't find the answer yet.
My code is like beyond.
I am taking my **greek characters** from UITextField, put them in InsertPersonToDatabase func and send them to database.

```
    -(BOOL)insertPersonToDatabase:(const char *)_name :(const char *)_surname :(const char *)_age;
{
    sqlite3 *database;
        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
       const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into person (name,surname,age) values ('%s','%s','%s')",_name,_surname,_age] UTF8String];
           NSLog(@"%s",sqlStatement);
       char *zErrMsg = 0;

        if (sqlite3_exec(database, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &zErrMsg)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Row inserted!!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Row DIDN'T inserted..");
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_close(database);
            return FALSE;
        }
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return TRUE;
}
```

BUT NSLog prints:
**insert into person (name,surname,age) values ('≈í√ü≈í¬±≈ì√Ö≈í√∏≈ì√ñ≈í¬™≈í¬±','≈í√ü≈í¬±≈ì√ë≈í‚àÇ≈í‚àë≈í¬•≈í‚àë≈í¬∫≈í‚àë≈ì√ë≈ì√Ö≈íœÄ≈í√∏≈ì√ñ','25')** and these are the values that saved in my database, not the greek characters that I have wrote in textfields.

Do anyone know the answer? Please help!!!!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [NSLog incorrect encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720052/nslog-incorrect-encoding).

> NSLog's %s format specifier is in the system encoding, which seems to
>   always be MacRoman and not unicode, so it can only display characters
>   in MacRoman encoding.

So, the issue is not in SQLite code, it is in NSLog

Comment: Hm... Thank you very much for your answer... I will check again!! I hope you are right and the problem is not the encoding!

Comment: @anvc You are welcome, please, notify me about checking results.

Comment: I checked that but these values (≈í√ü≈í¬±≈ì√Ö≈í√) inserted also into the database fields not just on LSLog... :(

Comment: how do you extract those filds from database? How do you check values?

Comment: I put the .db file to "Sqlite Manager" (extension on Firefox). I see the new fields but they are just like i said...

Comment: So, do you think that Squlite Manager tried to decode your string as UTF-8 string? How can it know that char string is encoded with UTF-8? Did you set any configurations to view it as UTF-8 string?

Comment: I think        `const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into person (name,surname,age) values ('%s','%s','%s')",_name,_surname,_age] UTF8String];` do the job.

Comment: Yes, it do job for ENCODING with UTF-8, but DECODING job should performs Squlite Manager (to make it readable for human)

Comment: I saw the DB Settings tab in SQLite Manager and UTF8 is checked on encoding field, if you mean that.

Comment: where do you extract your fields from database? what result do you get  If you use NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString]; NSLog(@"database string:%@", myNSString); Is it what you expect? (cString extracted from database)

Comment: I extract them into labels or textfield. But the problem is that these values are inserted into database like àÇ≈í‚àë≈í¬•≈í‚à. When i try to write greek characters in SqliteManager with 'insert into table....name='Νικος'", are saved as real greek characters.

Comment: If i use that you wrote, i see the same value that i see from SqliteManager. If in SqliteManager i see greek words, i see them on the label that i extract this value. If in my database the word is like àÇ≈í‚àë≈í¬•≈í‚à  , i see the same on the label. I hope you understand me!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Pavel!!! I found out why happened this. When i was taking the textfield values, i was converting them from NSString to const char to put them in db function for inserting to db, using 'const char *x = [y UTF8String]; Thank you again!